# getCollection of orders where completion date is today

Tags: product, magento-1, product-attribute, collection

I need to get a collection of all orders where the status is changed to completed today.

Currently i'm doing this:

```
$fromTime = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('yesterday midnight'));

$yesterdaysOrders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromTime))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE));
```

But with this I only get orders CREATED today - not the once completed today.

Comment: If you need a more exact solution than the accepted one, there is also the `sales_flat_order_status_history` table which holds the exact date an order was completed on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by replacing `created_at` with `updated_at`.

Please note that if you update the order after it has been completed, then this data will change. Magento does not store the `completed_at` date out of the box.